# Facebook POST request failure

Tags: python, json, facebook, post, request

Im having trouble when i try to do a POST request of anything (greeting, persistent_menu, get_started) to facebook. The response is always :

> {"error":{"message":"(#100) Requires one of the params:
>   get_started,persistent_menu,target_audience,whitelisted_domains,greeting,account_linking_url,payment_settings,home_url","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"AK39y2gSSOU"}}

here is my code:

```
PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN = <MY_PAGE_ACCES_TOKEN>

url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=' + PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN

data = {'greeting': '{"locale":"default", "text":"Hola {{user_first_name}}!"}'}

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data))
```

I really need to do this, can somebody help?

Thanks

Comment: just checking the documentation, it's saying url as `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>`. Maybe try `url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=' + PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN`

Comment: also, whenever I used `requests.post`, my `data =` was never a string. shouldn't that just be: `r = requests.post(url, data=data)` and looking at the error, it's saying it's not getting that parameter. So this would be the first thing I'd try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try, the following and tell me if/what error comes back:

```
PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN = <MY_PAGE_ACCES_TOKEN>

url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=' + PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN


data = {'greeting': '[{"locale":"default", "text":"Hola {{user_first_name}}!"}]'}

r = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

Comment: Response: {"error":{"message":"(#100) param greeting must be an array.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"Dz4iufsUmu\/"}}
STATUS_CODE: 400

Comment: ok. well that's getting you closer. looks like your `param greeting must be an array.`

Comment: so try:`data = {'greeting': [{"locale":"default", "text":"Hola {{user_first_name}}!"}]}`

Comment: Im getting the same error: "param greeting must be an array."

Comment: data = {'greeting': '[{"locale":"default", "text":"Hola {{user_first_name}}!"}]'}

This works, i was missing the quotations, thank you!

Comment: @Franmuzzio, thats what you put in? ah ok. yes. I see it.